# While_Run_For_loop_In_bash-Permission-denied

Tags: bash, git

When I'm executing the bash script it said permission denied on a line. below the script and other details.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/opt/gitlab/backups/ -amin +60 |grep tar | cut -d '/' -f 6 > 
/tmp/delete-files.txt
chmod +rw /var/opt/gitlab/backups/*.tar
chmod +rw /tmp/delete-files.txt
for i in `/tmp/delete-files.txt`
do
rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/backups/$i

[root@git opt]# ./asaaa
./asaaa: line 10: /tmp/delete-files.txt: Permission denied'


 [root@git opt]#
 [root@git opt]# ll /tmp/delete-files.txt
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 100 Mar 11 12:43 /tmp/delete-files.txt
 [root@git opt]#
```

Help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Post the program entirely. Where is line 10?

Comment: Just another thought: why dont you use `find` to find all `*.tar` with `-amin +60` and run `-exec rm -f {};` ; That will delete those tar files

Comment: Looks like you can't write to /tmp/delete-files.txt

Comment: Geno Chen, it is mentioned Below.

1: #!/bin/bash
2: find /var/opt/gitlab/backups/ -amin +60 |grep tar | cut -d '/' -f 6 > /tmp/delete-files.txt
3: 
4: chmod +rw /var/opt/gitlab/backups/*.tar
5: chmod +rw /tmp/delete-files.txt
6: 
7: for i in `more /tmp/delete-files.txt`;
8: do
9: rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab/backups/$i;
10: done

Comment: Sonny, thanks for the update ill try and let you know.

Comment: monok, its root user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
for i in `/tmp/delete-files.txt`
```

Backticks mean [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). Your script will try to execute `/tmp/delete-files.txt`. This is not an executable file.

My guess is that what you wanted to do was:

```
for i in `cat /tmp/delete-files.txt`
```

Ie. execute cat command to print the contents of the `/tmp/delete-files.txt` and then loop through each of the printed lines in the for loop.